# XMLHTTPRequest::send() Method Not Doing Anything

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, xmlhttprequest

This is my first time trying to use XMLHttpRequest (to upload a file dragged on to a web page) and I can't get it to do anything. I have the following Javascript code in my web page:

```
          function upload(file)
          {              
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", file);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                
            xhr.open("POST", "servlet/UploadServlet", false);                                               
            xhr.send(formData);               
          }
```

I placed my servlet class `UploadServlet` and my web page within the "examples" directory structure of my Tomcat server. But while I'm able to execute the `HelloWordServlet`example via a link on my page, I'm unable to get the XmlHttpRequest.send() to do anything. But I have been able to verifry that the Javascript code prior to that line is working, i.e., the file passed into the routine was successfully appended to the FormData object. A look into the server logs revealed nothing, and there wasn't anything when I brought up the console log either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you get anything at all in the browser developer tools console that suggests failure? how about in the browser developer tools network tab? any indication that the request is happening? P.S. sending a file synchronously is a *Very Bad Idea™* - try changing the request to be asynchronous (remove the false, or change it to true) - see if that helps. Also, which browser are you using? It's unusual to have absolutely nothing in the console about this request

Comment: I didn't see any messages in any of the tabs you mention that seem to be relevant to the XHR send, and changing the request to be asynchronous didn't make a difference. I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem wasn't with XmlHttpRequest, but with the servlet itself: I hadn't added it to the relevant mappings in `web.xml`